# How to change the default gnome text highlight color?

Tags: gnome, themes

I'm more used to the blue highlighting when you select text and the general highlighting when opening a gnome window. In the standard and dark themes of Focal Fossa, the default highlighting is orange. I use the standard theme and would like to change highlight colour to blue that is provided in the Adwaita light theme. Is there a way to customise this on 20.04?

I have Tweaks installed but I cannot change this specific setting.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by settings themes from gnome-look.org. The blue Yaru theme is just thr thing I needed.